# ¿Es posible agregar espacios en blanco a un número?

Tags: python, python-3.x

disculpen pero es posible agregar espacios a un str por ejemplo:

yo ingreso un numero por input el "123456789", y que el código haga esto:

1234 567 89, agregar espacios vacíos entre el 4 y 5 - 7 y 8.

Gracias de antemano y que Dios los bendiga.

```
num1 = input("123456789")

SALIDA: #Lo que deseo que salga

1234 567 89
```

Comment: eso seria string

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo, por ejemplo `print(' '.join((num1[:4], num1[4:7], num1[7:])))` ¿Cómo determinas las posiciones donde  insertar los espacio? ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Si estuve buscando códigos por Internet para poder intentarlo, pero sin éxito. 
Quisiera que siempre siga el mismo patrón, al insertar un numero de 9 dígitos que a los 4 primeros dígitos le añada un espacio y que a los 3 siguientes otro espacio.

Comment: No queda claro con qué criterio insertas los espacios. ¿Es al encontrar ciertas cifras en concreto, como el 4 y 5, o el 7 y 8, independientemente de dónde estén? ¿O es separar por grupos de tamaño prefijado, en tu caso 4-3-2? ¿Y si el dato introducido por el usuario no tiene exactamente 9 cifras como en tu ejemplo?

Comment: No no, lo deseo como regla general, puedo insertar otro numero como: 987654321 y que haga lo mismo, 9876 543 21.

Comment: print(' '.join((num1[:4], num1[4:7], num1[7:]))). Funciona a la perfección amigo, Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

una forma fácil de obtener ese resultado seria realizando varia subcadenas. del string inicial con sus indices:
ejemplo:

```
numeros ="123456789"
numeros_format =numeros[0:4]+" "+ numeros[4:7]+" "+ numeros[7:10]
print(numeros_format)
```

con los indices lo único que se realizar es extraer datos de la cadena.